# ASP.NET MVC 5, Entity Framework, Ninject and Multi Tenancy Setup

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, multi-tenant

I am trying to find the best approach for a multi tenancy setup for an application I am working on. The current application is specifically for basketball but would like to use the same codebase for football.

The application would change colors, logo, and some other pieces of code and views might be shown or hidden.  This will all be based on the URL of the application for sport tenant to use.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5, Ninject and Entity Framework 6.  I am going to create a Tenant table in my database that stores the URL and other related information to it.

When the application starts up what is the best way to retrieve the tenant and store it for that user?  Keep in mind the user may navigate to the other sport site, keep same login, but would load only the information related to that tenant.  Would a cookie be the best bet here?  I will need a way to access the tenant through the services layer also.

I may use https://github.com/jbogard/EntityFramework.Filters for the Entity Framework filtering on certain tables only related to that sport.  However how can I access the TenantID to do this?  Would a static factory of some sort work?

Comment: I assume you meant to call it tenancy, not tendency? :)

Comment: Yep sorry there you go

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [AspNet.Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity), which would allow you to authenticate users/tenants, store profile information for each user/tenant and to use roles or claims for authorization for different parts of the website.

Comment: I am already using asp.net membership and wont be reworking it to do that.

Comment: Should be useful to add this to the question then.

Comment: I guess but the user is totally separate from the tenant.  The same user can access all tenants.  I want to show different stuff based on tenant, user doesnt matter.

Comment: @MikeFlynn - Typically multi-tenancy requires that users be specific to the tenant.  So it sounds to me like you just want a site with multiple areas.

Comment: Yea pretty much, different sites, same codebase, can be used by same user on all of them.

Comment: I think Erik literally meant use Areas. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Why they are going to use the exact same views and controllers in the areas 98% of the time?

Comment: @MikeFlynn How did you solve your problem? As I have similar kind of problem i.e. we have Educational Enterprise Resource Planning System which has about 10 modules (Exam, Result, Finance, ExtraActivities, Library, AcademicPrograms, HR and more) and it was built for single tenant now would like to extend and re-design for multi-tenancy Saas having same-schema based and same database. Any idea or links will be much helpful. Thank you.