# How do sites like shopify.com, github.io, volusion.com, support multiple subdomains per user?

Tags: html, e-commerce, platform

I like the idea that third part apps run at `*.github.io` `*.shopify.com` `*.volusion.com` works, people make own pages (modify/use template), and host inside.
I'm interested in architecture, how all of this happen?

- Do they save files in disk, or write inside database
- How easily manage dynamic subdomains?
- What happens behind the scene?
- What language they use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [multitenancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy). It can be achieved in a number of ways with on many different server platforms. There are a number of pieces, for example:

- URL rewriting rules handled at the load balancer or web server level to let `*.site.com` act as `site.com/users`, or something to that effect depending on your platform architecture
- A database of tenants (users) and their associated account names or subdomains
- Routing or resolution code that conditionally switches the database connection (or tables, or security modifiers, etc.) per request based on the calling tenant

Ultimately, a tenant is just a row in a database table somewhere, and the application is written in a generic way so that each tenant uses the same "base" code. How that works and how it is implemented can vary greatly between applications.

**Update**: Per your comment, here are some resources specifically dealing with tenancy in ASP.NET:

- [Simple Multitenancy With ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.dennisonpro.info/simple-multitenancy-with-asp-net-mvc-4/)
- [Developing Multi-tenant Applications for the Cloud, 3rd Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff966499.aspx) (free Microsoft ebook)
- [ASP.NET MVC 5, Entity Framework, Ninject and Multi Tenancy Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103610/asp-net-mvc-5-entity-framework-ninject-and-multi-tenancy-setup)
- [Multi-tenancy in ASP.NET MVC](http://codeofrob.com/entries/multi-tenancy-in-asp.net-mvc---controller-actions-part-i.html)

Comment: If you are interested in how this is achieved with a specific platform or language, consider updating your question to include those details. If you are interested in how this works on the server level, check out [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: The thing is "i dont know what question i need to ask"

Comment: Specially im interested in ASP.NET MVC implementation

Comment: Updated my answer to provide links to resources specifically dealing with doing this in ASP.NET.